# Blueprism, how to write collection to Excel but to merged cells

Tags: excel, blueprism, rpa

I have a Collection with the same fields as in the Excel File. 
I want to write that Collection to that Excel File, but the file has a specific format and there are cells that are merged together for example B2:B6 and when I write the collection he inserts into those cells, he doesn't recognize that the cells are merged. Is there a possible way to overcome that problem without needing to write every cell one single time?

Comment: Why don't you unmerge all cells first? Write an Unmerge routine and add it to the Excel VBO

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the value in a merged cell looks like (for B2:B6 example) [value][empty][empty][empty][empty], so if you know the range of merged cells in your table, you can insert empty values in the fields of your collection and then write it to your document.

Comment: ok that could be one possible solution, thank you. 

But what If I read from File1 the table to collection and want to write that collection to File2. In that case the Collection is already formated.

Comment: If you using Blue Prism Excel VBO action Get Worksheet Range as Collection, value from merget cells will looks like [value][empty][empty][empty][empty].

Comment: yes I use that action and the value doesn't look like that. I use blue prism version 5.4

Answer (score 0):

After many tryouts, I solved it by reading two of my Tables from excel into two seperate Collections.

Then I used the built in Action "Append Rows to Collection" from the "Utility - Collection Manipulation" Business Object. Now the two collectons are one. Then I Compare each field and search for duplications and delete these rows.

At the end there is a Collection which I can just paste into my excel file.